# How To Fix Broken Contacts Storage (Droid 3 v2.3.4)?

Tags: contacts, force-close, bloatware

## Symptoms

- **I receive a force close from `com.motorola.contacts` when I try to edit my contacts**
- I can view my contacts
- The issue started immediately after I tried removing the thousand pound bundle of bloatware that Verizon pushed to my phone.

### Avenues of Approach

1. #### Repairing the Stock Contact Storage

   What apps does com.motorola.contacts depend on?
     *(Bonus question:  How would I find that on my own; other than trial-in-error)*

   I have read that this app relies on some of the blur.yahoo bloatware.  I tried keeping those enabled, but I may have missed a vital one and if I did, it is no longer on my phone so I'll have to hunt for it.  Ideally, I won't have to re-enable this junk, which brings me to
2. #### Replace Contact Storage With Third-Party App

   I have been searching for contact app replacements and so far they seem to run on top of the stock contacts app (as in they will also allow me to view, but app.motorola.contacts crashes when I try to edit).  Example apps: [Contapps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5jb250YXBwcy5hbmRyb2lkIl0.), [Go Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contact&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qYmFwcHMuY29udGFjdCJd), as well as a few others.

   **Is it even possible to replace this system app?**
3. #### Use Alternate Version of the Stock Contact App

   I don't mean to ask you guys to do my experimenting for me, but could I take the contact storage app from a different system that doesn't require Junk.Yahoo:  Such as an older version of Android or one that doesn't come from Verizon?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Go Contacts. Based on my experience [Samsung Galaxy S2], it doesn't work well with Google Sync. But maybe other users don't have this issue. I still use the stock Contacts app.

Comment: Fair enough, but as I stated:  Those won't run anyway, they seem to run on top of the stock contact app - So when they try to edit the contact, `com.motorola.contacts` crashes.

Comment: Wow, that response is long overdue. Anyway, GO Contacts seems to be OK now. I haven't had any issues with Google Sync anymore. I recommend it now. :)

Comment: Haha, yeah I know.  I got a 2500 view badge that led me back here and I realized I never responded.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the contacts force close issue on my droid 3. I had frozen several apps with Titanium Backup. The fix was to unfreeze these 2 items:
  Yahoo contacts 2.3.4
and
  Yahoo! mail authenticator 2.3.4

Immediately my issues were resolved.

Running rooted stock rom

Hope this helps others. I have benefited plenty from others' posts. :)